# Calling IASetVertexBuffers makes all future calls to the device context cause a access violation(DX 11)

Tags: c++, directx-11, vertex-buffer

I have looked around and have not found an answer to this, this is the offending line of code: d3d->GetImmediateContext()->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, 0);

None of the passed in parameters are NULL(0x00000000)( The device context is also not null) but I still get an access violation error on every function call on the device context. The exception message I get is "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDFD6CC796 (d3d11.dll) in 2D Platformer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.". Again the weird thing is that it does this the next time I call any method on the device context, if I don't set the vertex buffer(Obviously nothing is drawn) then there is no crashes and I can call what ever I want.

Anyone else experienced a similar problem or does anyone have a suggestion of what could be causing this problem?

(If you need any clarification just ask)

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out exactly what was wrong, it seems that I was passing in 0 for the offset which counted as a null pointer throwing the access violation error since the program obviously did not have access to the address 0x00000000. Also I thought it broke on the line after but it does break during the appropriate line and not the line after. So to fix this problem all I had to do was passing in a variable like this: &offset for the offset parameter and it worked

```
unsigned int offset = 0;
d3d->GetImmediateContext()->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride,&offset);
```

I hope that this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Remember that ``IASetVertexBuffers`` take an array of pointers to ``ID3D11Buffer``, not a pointer to one. This makes the usage a little confusing at times.

Comment: Thanks, yeah earlier I did have a problem with that